# Active Directory : FOREST ISSUE - 2 AD , 1 Forest

Tags: dns, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, dhcp

i have 2 AD.

Both AD hosts DHCP and DNS. ( DNS1 is x.x.1.5 , DNS2 is x.x.1.6 )

Example First AD is down. Will the Whole Forest be down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. Your forest will continue up. Since your environment has two domains where when one crashes the other one will stabilize the service.
You will have to take back the crashed DC to have back the contingency, and make ensure some specifics such as

- Where are the master roles and get it online ASAP

Another thing to consider since there are two DHCP is to **Make sure they´re not delivering the same range of IPs to your network**.

Comment: thank you for the answer. even though this is back in 2017 , i just want to appreciate the assistance by marking it as an answer